# Facing an issue in azure search index

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

```
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
    SearchField,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    VectorSearch,
    HnswAlgorithmConfiguration,
    HnswParameters,
    VectorSearchAlgorithmMetric,
    ExhaustiveKnnAlgorithmConfiguration,
    ExhaustiveKnnParameters,
    VectorSearchProfile,
    AzureOpenAIVectorizer,
    AzureOpenAIParameters,
    SemanticConfiguration,
    SemanticSearch,
    SemanticPrioritizedFields,
    SemanticField,
    SearchIndex
)
```

...

```
cannot import name 'AzureOpenAIVectorizer' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models' (C:\Users\subramaniann\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\azure\search\documents\indexes\models\__init__.py)
version using azure-search-documents==11.6.0b1
```

...

I tried doing: !pip install azure-core --pre --upgrade and !pip install azure-search-documents --pre --upgrade
still it is showing error

Comment: use`pip install azure-search-documents azure-identity azure-core`

Answer (score 1):

The issue with importing the `AzureOpenAIVectorizer` class from the `azure.search.documents.indexes.models` module occurs due to an installation problem.

`pip uninstall azure-search-documents`
`pip install azure-search-documents==11.6.0b1`

[image]

The command `python -m venv myenv` creates a virtual environment named "myenv" in your current directory.

`python -m venv myenv`

`myenv\Scripts\activate` is used to activate the virtual environment. Once activated, your terminal or command prompt session will use the Python interpreter and packages installed within the virtual environment rather than the global Python environment.
`myenv\Scripts\activate`

**Install the below packages:**

`pip install python-dotenv azure-search-documents==11.6.0b1 azure-storage-blob azure-identity`

The code for azure-search-vector-samples for azure-search-integrate is taken from [git](https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/integrated-vectorization/azure-search-integrated-vectorization-sample.ipynb) and [requirements.txt](https://github.com/Azure/azure-search-vector-samples/blob/main/demo-python/code/integrated-vectorization/azure-search-integrated-vectorization-sample-requirements.txt).

```py
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
    SearchField,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    VectorSearch,
    HnswAlgorithmConfiguration,
    HnswParameters,
    VectorSearchAlgorithmMetric,
    ExhaustiveKnnAlgorithmConfiguration,
    ExhaustiveKnnParameters,
    VectorSearchProfile,
    AzureOpenAIVectorizer,
    AzureOpenAIParameters,
    SemanticConfiguration,
    SemanticSearch,
    SemanticPrioritizedFields,
    SemanticField,
    SearchIndex
)
```

**Output:**

[image]